# What is the type of objects/classes in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

What goes in the `???` in the snippet below to make this runnable code happy?

```
const classes: ??? = [
  HTMLElement,
  Document,
  ResizeObserver,
];

for (const Class of classes) {
  const proto = Class.prototype;
  for (const name in proto) {
    console.log(Class.name, name);
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMA2BDCECmED0AqAXDA-IVhjALwwDaAUDDABIAqAsgDICi8qAtqmFADQ0YAERDAArjz6DaAJXQBLAF6oA8gCM0AJwBuqLYIC6AbipUAZiC0wAFKEiwAwkhQwQ5uC7QQAlDADeQvbQMAAOWiBQIGQwzsgQAHThkZEAnqGoprSW1nbgIWCIPDAKYGERUX6BtLTBIJwJ8CAA5jZxKAmFPPwwXag+WTAAvlQjQA)

Note, I've commented out `???` in the playground. The question is, what type goes there?

Also note: I have 50+ classes so listing out every class in the type is not a solution. I'm looking for a generic solution. Ideally one that only has to be put where the `???` is as the rest should be inferable.

Note: I've been using `Function[]` but [@typescript-eslint/ban-types](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/) says that's bad. Is this an appropriate use or is there a better solution?

Comment: There are no errors in the playground. What do you mean by `make code happy` ?

Comment: But you don't have any errors and TS not complaining. As you might have noticed, TS is able to infer `classes` array. What exactly do you expect? For instance, you can use [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0nkOw) approach, however, I think it is best to avoid using explicit type annotation in this case

Comment: You can check [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEB92N) example

Comment: @Anatoly, I thought it would be obvious that I've commented out the ??? on the playground. I want a type where the comment is. What type goes there?

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMA2BDCECmEBcMAUUCeADqiAGYwASAKgLIAyAovKgLapiwA+M+RpMAIiGABXVuxhcexMgCV0ASwBeqAPIAjNACcAbqk0BKANoBdGAF4YhgFAwKNBkzFQANDYFDRbF27kQlqjT1dTVdjAG4rKxIQTRxQSFgAYSQUGD4EZDQIfRgAbzd46BgCTRAoEHMYZMyAOhKyssJUCNto2OxC2DBEVhh5MGLS8pz821tCkCYa+BAAc2xqlBru1mcYFdR9FpgAXys9oA ?

Comment: @Anatoly, no, I mean something generic that takes any object constructor that has a prototype.

Comment: There is no way you can use a type definition there. The closest thing would be `type Class = { new (...args: any[]): {}; prototype: {}; }` but that would rapidly become unusable. Don't use a type annotation for generic things, use generics when applicable